# how to use regex to find a name in datatables

Tags: java, javascript, regex, validation

Currently i am using a regex function which makes comparisons with the first word only. for example the name is "John Dave". If i search the keyword "John" it would return the result correctly as John Dave. but if i search "Dave" its not able to find out. 
This is the function i am using currently. I want to update the function to compare with the full name.

```
criteria.and("vehicle_info.veh_reg_no").regex("^" + sb.getVehicle_reg(), "i");
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: The `^` marks the beginning of the string, so whatever follows it cannot have anything in front of it. Also, why use regex if you want to search for a literal string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the "^" character, you could use:

```
r = new RegExp('Dave', 'i')
r.test('John Dave')
```

That will return: `true`

Comment: will this one do the same                                            `criteria.and("insured_name").regex( sb.getInsured_name(),"i");`

Comment: Right, It's just another way to use RegExp, but focused in the example you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

This regular expression: `"^" + sb.getVehicle_reg()` will result into something along this lines for a user name of `John`: `^John`. This means that the regex engine will start matching the string from the very beginning, and this is why `John Dave` will be matched by `^John` but not `^Dave`.

To make it search the entire string, simply remove the extra `^` in front to have something like so: `sb.getVehicle_reg()`. That should look into the entire string.

Comment: i changed my function but still it doesn't work. `criteria.and("insured_name").regex( sb.getInsured_name(),"i");`